# Asus PN50 mini-PC: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: drivers, temperature, sensors, fan

I am running Linux Mint on a PN50 Ryzen 5 4500U. Fan is very loud and I think it can make it quieter with a little bit of fan RPM control. However, I am not able to detect the fan speed:

```
$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

My `sensors` output is

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +52.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +52.5°C
```

The `sensors-detect` output is here https://pastebin.com/VsZuqiuL

Any ideas how to add the fan sensor to the list of sensors? and CPU core temperature?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your distribution or kernel, but you need the latest kernels to get the most out of this machine. It may be that better power/temp management is available with a 5.8 kernel or after. AMD released enough information for good driver support, it takes a while to migrate to the distributions, though. The sensors may be better supported in later kernels, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding grub kernal paramater "acpi_enforce_resources=lax"